# How to exclude certain entries from meta ordering in django?

Tags: python, django

Hi I have the following given:

```
class Copy(CommonLibraryBaseModel):

    signature = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Signatur')

    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['signature']
```

What I want to do now is to define a ordering along the signature (this is already done with `ordering = ['signature']`), but exclude all signatures that start with a certain substring. How would I do that using the Meta class?

Thanks

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "exclude"? Do you want to remove them from the queryset, or do you want to order those specific items in some other way?

Comment: remove them from the queryset

Comment: That's something different from ordering. Instead you can use the QuerySet method exclude() `Copy.objects.exclude(signature__startswith='foo_')` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exclude